# "Permission denied" when trying to access static files after deployment

Tags: python, django, cpanel

Having issues loading static files in my django app after deployment.

I know I am supposed to set static_root as the path to where I want to create the static folder and then run python manage.py collectstatic (not sure if I have to do this if I already have a static folder).

Here is the structure of my project

```
gradboost
-->__pycache__
-->classroom
       __init__.py
       apps.py
       decorators.py
       forms.py
       models.py
       urls.py
------>templates
------>templatetags
-->django_school
       __pycache__
       __init__.py
       settings.py
       urls.py
       wsgi.py
-->public
-->static
-->templates
-->tmp
   manage.py
   passenger_wsgi.py
public_html
```

This is what I currently have on settings.py

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/gradboost/public/static'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
```

Running collectstatic returns this error message

> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/gradientboostmvp'

Here is what I get when I print settings.**dict**

```
{'_wrapped': <Settings "django_school.settings">, 'INSTALLED_APPS': ['django.contrib.auth','django.contrib.admin', 'django.contrib.contenttypes', 'django.contrib.sessions', 'django.contrib.messages', 'django.contrib.staticfiles', 'django.contrib.humanize', 'crispy_forms', 'classroom'], 'LOGGING_CONFIG': 'logging.config.dictConfig', 'LOGGING': {}, 'FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME': None, 'DEBUG': False, 'DEFAULT_TABLESPACE': '', 'DATABASES': {'default': {'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', 'NAME': '/home/thegqvow/gradboost/db.sqlite3', 'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': False, 'AUTOCOMMIT': True, 'CONN_MAX_AGE': 0, 'OPTIONS': {}, 'TIME_ZONE': None, 'USER': '', 'PASSWORD': '', 'HOST': '', 'PORT': '', 'TEST': {'CHARSET': None, 'COLLATION': None, 'NAME': None, 'MIRROR': None}}}, 'ABSOLUTE_URL_OVERRIDES': {}, 'USE_I18N': True, 'LANGUAGE_CODE': 'en-us', 'LOCALE_PATHS': [], 'DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE': '', 'AUTH_USER_MODEL': 'classroom.User', 'SECRET_KEY': '**'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your static root is configure wrong - I usually configure the full path using `BASE_DIR`

```
# Should contain /path/to/gradboost
BASE_DIR =  os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(self.BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'public/static'),
]
```

I changed the STATIC_ROOT and additional static folders, seems more logical that way.

Comment: Thanks. I get the error FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/public/static' with this.

Comment: Sorry I updated the answer - There was a `/` too much in `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'public/static')`

Comment: thanks. not sure why but the staticfiles are still not getting loaded in my pages

Comment: You still get the permission error? Maybe print all the paths from `from django.conf.settings`: `from django.conf import settings`  --> `settings.__dict__` and show the permission of the folder `ls -lha gradboost `

Comment: btw: where and what is `gradientboostmvp`, seems like a random folder somewhere in static. You need to check the permissions of that folder. You may have copied it with a different user

Comment: that's a typo gradboost/gradientboostmvp are one in the same. I have managed to collect static and printed the paths (in my answer)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206366/discussion-between-mathias-and-emm).